# Let X be the total number of rolls when we roll a die until the the sum of dots of two consecutively obtained faces is 7

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Let X be the total number of rolls when we roll a die until the the sum of dots of two consecutively obtained faces is 7. Find ($EX^2 + X + 1$).

Attempt:
X is a geometric random variable because we throw the die until we get a success, which is consecutives are 7. For each throw we have 1/6 chance on getting the right consecutive die.

We know that Expectation for X, since its geometric, is 1/p but we throw we need to throw the first die, so it is 1+1/p which is 7. We know that VarX is $q/{p}^2$ and also $VarX=EX^2-(EX)^2$ then $EX^2=VarX+(EX)^2=30+49=79$ But what is X in this case, how do I derive it? I am not even sure if my solution is correct until this point too. Regards.

Comment: What does $(EX2 + X + 1)$ mean?

Comment: fixed it, it should have been $EX^2$ where 2 is over X.

Comment: "$X$ is a geometric random variable because we throw the die until we get a success". Not really (or you need to justify it), because the success does not depend on the result of the "experiment" (die result) alone, but also on the previous one.

Comment: Do you mean $E(X^2+X+1)$?

Comment: "But what is $X$ in this case, how do I derive it?"  You've just been talking about the mean and variance of $X$.  Is this some other $X$?  It's very hard for me to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the major source of your difficulty is that you are not writing down carefully what you are doing.  I'm not saying that you should write up every problem as if you intend to publish it, at least not while you are working it out, but when you find yourself confused, it often helps to go back and write things explicitly.

In this case, you have the right idea.  $X=Y+1$, where Y is a geometrically-distributed random variable with parameter $p=1/6$.  Since you know all about $Y$, just express your problem in terms of $Y$.

$$E(X^2+X+1)=E((Y+1)^2+Y+2)=E(Y^2)+3E(Y)+3$$

I feel sure you can finish it from here.

Comment: But the problem asks specifically $(EX^2+X+1)$ which really confuses me. Maybe there's a typo then. Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: @70pr4k That must be a typo.  It doesn't make much sense at it is.